# How to receive a byte array and header content in a ASP.NET Core Web API Controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, webclient

I need to receive a content together with a byte array in a c# ASP.NET Core Web API application.

```html
**--HttpClient (console Application)**  

                Dictionary<int, byte[]> fileparts = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
                int bufferSize = 1000 * 1024;

                byte[] buffer;
                string filePath = @"D:\Extra\Songs\test.mp3";
                using (FileStream fileData = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    int i = 1;
                    while (fileData.Position < fileData.Length)
                    {

                        if (index + bufferSize > fileData.Length)
                        {
                            buffer = new byte[(int)fileData.Length - index];
                            fileData.Read(buffer, 0, ((int)fileData.Length - index));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                            fileData.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        }

                        fileparts.Add(i, buffer);
                        index = (int)fileData.Position;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                
 while (fileparts.Count() != 0)
 {               
      var data = fileparts.First();          
  var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);//byte content
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "test" };
                        fileContent.Headers.Add("id", id);
                        fileContent.Headers.Add("name", name);
                        fileContent.Headers.Add("length", length);
                        if (fileparts.Count() == 1)
                          fileContent.Headers.Add("IsCompleted", "true");
                        else
                          fileContent.Headers.Add("IsCompleted", "false");
                          
                    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                       content.Add(fileContent);
                       // Make a call to Web API 
                        var result = client.PostAsync("/api/file", fileContent).Result;
                        if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            fileparts.Remove(data.Key);
                    }

**--WebApi Core ApiController**

    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
        {
    /*i need to get the content here , for some reason existing .NET libraries does not work here
    like 
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        FilePart part = null;
       
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider); -- request.content not available 
        using (Stream fileStream = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    part = provider.Contents[0].Headers.GetData(); //public static FilePart GetData name,length,id 
                    part.Data = fileStream.ReadFully();
    */    
    }
```

the back end I have working but can't find a way of the new asp.net core controller parsing fileobject and data from client post through to the service! Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as always...

Comment: you are passing the `ByteArrayContent` to the controller but not the `MultipartFormDataContent` are you sure about this?

Comment: in this line `var result = client.PostAsync("/api/file", fileContent).Result;`

Comment: Hi @Niladri yes It's a mistake, it should be  var result = client.PostAsync("/api/file", content).Result;  not fileContent

Comment: I have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this sucessfully in the past:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile formFile)
{
    using (Stream stream = formFile.OpenReadStream())
    {
         //Perform necessary actions with file stream
    }
}
```

I believe you'll also need to change your client code to match the parameter name:

`fileContent.Headers.Add("name", "formFile");`

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your controller action method like below to accept `ByteArrayContent` OR `MultipartFormDataContent` as required. I have used `[FromBody]` attribute for the model binding in POST.

Here is more info on `[FromBody]`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

```
public class FileController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] MultipartFormDataContent content)
        {
         MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        FilePart part = null;
         // access the content here 
         await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        // rest of the code
       }
   }
```

as discussed before you should be using `content` to post to this API like below

`var result = client.PostAsync("/api/file", content).Result;`

Comment: With [FromBody] attribute client exit with 'UnsupportedMediaType', it seems not reach the server side POST.

Comment: @Lakmal which version of web api are you using ?

Comment: @Lakmal have you changed it to  `var result = client.PostAsync("/api/file", content).Result;`

Comment: you mean "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1" ?

Comment: Yes, 
var result = client.PostAsync("/api/file", content).Result;

Comment: I tried it without [FromBody] attribute (Post(MultipartFormDataContent content)). and then read all contents of multipart message into MultipartMemoryStreamProvider (await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)) but provider.Contents[0] is missing

Comment: is that version issue or something else ?

Comment: @Lakmal it does not seem like a version issue for byte array in web api 2 we had "bson" formatter which you needed to add as mediatypeformatter but in .net core I am not sure if it's still there. Are you using JSON.NET? then you can try to serialize the input and then try

Comment: Same exception as @Lakmal UnsupportedMediaType on core 2.2